# Original arguements get overwritten

Tags: python, parameter-passing

So I have this function in Python:

```
def newk(kor, flds):
    field=0.5*flds
    knw=[]

    for i in range(flds):
        ktemp=kor
        if ktemp[2]+i>field:
            ktemp[2]-=(i-1)
        else:
            ktemp[2]+=i
        knw+=[ktemp]
        print knw
        print ktemp
        print kor, '\n'
    return knw
```

which is called by:

```
knew=newk(kvals, folds)
```

My original kvals gets overwritten for some reason. Kvals is a list.
Also ktemp keeps accumulating like knw suppose to and it screws
everything up.  My output looks like this:

> [[0.05, 0.05, 0.166667]] [0.05, 0.05, 0.166667] [0.05, 0.05, 0.166667]
>
> [[0.05, 0.05, 1.166667], [0.05, 0.05, 1.166667]] [0.05, 0.05,
>   1.166667] [0.05, 0.05, 1.166667]
>
> [[0.05, 0.05, -0.8333330000000001], [0.05, 0.05, -0.8333330000000001],
>   [0.05, 0.05, -0.8333330000000001]] [0.05, 0.05, -0.8333330000000001]
>   [0.05, 0.05, -0.8333330000000001]
>
> K point values are: [0.05, 0.05, -0.8333330000000001]     (original  kvals was `[0.05,0.05,0.166667]`)

But I need my output to look like this: knw would be `[[0.05, 0.05, 0.166667],[0.05, 0.05, 1.166667],[0.05, 0.05, -0.833333]`, kval would be `[0.05, 0.05, 0.166667]`
Also, when i change ktemp=kor in the loop to constant ktemp=[0.05, 0.05, 0.166667] everything works.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It might help to let us know which language that is in for a start – preferably by adding the corresponding tag. I guess you can remove the “overwrite” one while you’re at it, that one is not helpful.

Comment: looks like python with broken indentation.

Comment: I don't know why it broke my indentation, but the body of the function is all indented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `ktemp=kor` you end up with two names pointing at the same list object & so a modification to `ktemp` is the same as modifying `kor`.  If you want a *copy* of the list, you need to say `ktemp = kor[:]` (assuming `kor` is just numbers - if you want a 'deep copy' of a list with complex objects, that's a different issue).